# pine script - take profit using points from entry instead of percentage

Tags: pine-script

I want to set up a strategy.exit based off a specific number of points from entry of trade. Is it as simple as using <from_entry = ID>? But then what would be used in strategy.exit to trigger the sale based on the entry price plus (for long) or minus (for short) in point terms to trigger the exit?

Answer (score 1):

the profit and loss arguments of strategy.exit are already based in points. I would try these. For price levels you can use limit and stop args